# How do I search for invisible characters in a database table column?

Tags: mysql, sql, html-entities

The database table in question has a unique username column. When the usernames are listed in phpMyAdmin or SqlYog, a duplicate for at least one username appears.

When the username is displayed on a web page and the HTML is inspected, it can be seen that the duplicate username is preceded by an HTML entity `&rlm;` ([right-to-left mark](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)) which is not shown on the page because it has no visual representation or associated symbol.

Trying to search for the entity:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE username LIKE '%&rlm;%';
```

returns no results, because the invisible symbol not the entity is stored.

When exporting to Excel from SqlYog, it appears as â€ in Excel.

Comment: Does your HTML contains the entity or the symbol?

Comment: can you provide a [mre] because it seems to work https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0fd73ad53abb9cde916ac3470c15d4e8

Comment: @Akina the entity `&rlm;`.

Comment: Thanks @nbk. The column must then not contain the entity but the symbol which has no visual representation.

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=480d98f3d6997e2d50f94baa19c6c273) cannot reproduce your issue. Edit it, use your data, provide the link with the issue.

Comment: Maybe if you show the schema for this table it will help explain and some example data

Comment: What I will try is to remove characters normally in usernames like letters, numbers, underscores,etc. from each username, then see which usernames are not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the visible characters that are normally in usernames from each username, then check which usernames are still not empty but appear empty.

```
SELECT username, 
       REGEXP_REPLACE(username, "[\\.,{}<>\'a-z0-9@_-]", '') AS second_username 
  FROM mytable 
  HAVING second_username <> '';
```

Comment: you are missing A-Z still we want to see the data and table that will not show up with the like statement

Comment: [A-Z] is not normally allowed in usernames.

Comment: If A-z is not allowed so why you let people enter non visible characters?